# Plone 3.3.5 on CentOS 5.7 Apache 2.2 Virtual Host RewriteRule Issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, plone, zope, httpd.conf

I installed Plone 3.3.5 on CentOS 5.7 and put Zope behind Apache, in order for URL to "see" my Plone web site, I used the concepts of virtual host and rewrite rule. However, the URL that results is not pretty, although the web page does come up correctly.

### The edited httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost 164.67.141.42:80

<VirtualHost 164.67.141.42:80>
    ServerName www2.oid.ucla.edu
    ServerAlias www2.oid.ucla.edu 
    ServerAdmin web@oid.ucla.edu
    ServerSignature On

    CustomLog  /var/log/httpd/www2-access.log combined
    ErrorLog   /var/log/httpd/www2-error.log
    LogLevel warn

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www2.oid.ucla.edu:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/www2.oid.ucla.edu:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
   ProxyVia On

   # prevent the webserver from being used as proxy
   <LocationMatch "^[^/]">
      Deny from all
      </LocationMatch>
   </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

---

The resulting URL = "http://www2.oid.ucla.edu:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/www2.oid.ucla.edu:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/"

The URL should be = "http://www2.oid.ucla.edu/"

If I add "P" to RewriteRule ^/(.*) `http://www2.oid.ucla.edu:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/www2.oid.ucla.edu:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]`
it errors "Service Temporarily Unavailable" on web page.

The error log says:
[error] (13)Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 164.67.141.42:8080 (*) failed

What could be causing this?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure, but I have always used ProxyPass directive myself, not RewriteRule

Comment: E.g. http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hosting/apache.html#load-balanced-apache-virtual-host-configuration

Comment: Take a look at http://betabug.ch/zope/witch, it'll generate the correct rewrite rule for you. Note the initial / is not present when accessing the root of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have mod_proxy active and enabled, and that your apache is set up to allow proxying. The 'P' in '[L,P]' means 'proxy', and mod_rewrite won't do that by itself

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought you should maybe look at your zope config settings, thinking that it might be bound to localhost but your example without the proxy flag would have triggered a redirect to the domain name which I gather actually returned a real Plone response.  So that's probably not it.

You might have an issue with the SELinux settings.  To test that, try this as root...

$  echo 0 > /selinux/enforce

This will temporary disable SELinux.  If the proxy now works, you've found the issue.  In this case, the following might help you...

$  /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

But I suggest you don't apply this fix until you've read up on SELinux a bit more.  It's probably not wise to twist knobs on your server's security configuration without understanding what you are doing.

Probably not directly relevant to your question but here are few other bits of advice:

1) You don't need the ServerAlias line.  The domain listed is already listed as the ServerName.

2) Others have already pointed out that you need the 'P' flag.  The 'L' flag by itself will, in this case, just generate a redirect, which is not what you want.  With a 'P' flag, the 'L' is implied so just [P] will do.

3) The betabug.ch site mentioned by Martijn is okay but note that it also incorrectly adds the 'L' flag and assumes that an initial '/' may not be present in some requests (in the VirtualHost context, the path will always begin with a '/' -- it's only in Directory context that you have to worry about this which you never have in a Plone setup).  Neither of these will break the RewriteRule -- they just needlessly clutter up the config.

4) You don't need the LocationMatch bit to protect against Proxy abuse.  You're setting up a reverse proxy, not a forward proxy.  It's the forward proxies that need special care.  If you're not sure if you've got a forward proxy -- or if you're paranoid -- just explicitly turn off forward proxy behavior with "ProxyRequests off". You don't usually need to worry about this as ProxyRequests is off by default.

Answer (score 0):

$ setenforce 0

on the other and, read some documentation of selinux. There is a way to make it swallows this apache configuration.

SELinux, is your friend, for shure, but treat HIM with care :)